# Longlistselector contents receiving events whilst scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

As part of my current mobile project, I want to display a longlistselector with custom rows. Each row will have a slider inside it. The slider is used to set a percentage value. It's very easy to mock this up using datatemplates.

For example

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="longListSelectorState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="499" Margin="30,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376">                
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></Slider>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>                             
        </phone:LongListSelector>                
    </Grid>
```

Unfortunately, once the list is populated, as you scroll through the list, if you hit one of the sliders its value gets set. This makes scrolling through the list very awkward. There doesn't seem to be a way of telling the list not to allow controls to receive touch events whilst the list is being scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Windows phone 8. Even though LongListSelector has some manipulation events such as ManipulationCompleted, ManipulationStarted etc the code put inside these event handlers will not fire in LongListSelectors, Panorama and Pivot controller because these are part of the framework and considered as handled.